# R row selection providing partial results

Tags: r

I'm having an issue, which I have found a solution for, but would like to understand what was going on in the original coding.

So I started with a table pulled from an SQL database and wanted information for 1 client, who is covered by 2 client numbers.

Originally I was running this to select those account numbers.

```
match <- c("C524",'5568')
gtc <- gtc[gtc$AccountNumber == match,]
```

However this was only returning about half of the desired results, and the results returned vary at different times (this was running as a weekly report), and depending on the PC running it.

Now, I've set up a loop which works fine and extracts all the results, but would really like to know what was going on with the original query.

```
match <- c("C524",'5568')
for (each in match) {
  gtcLoop<- gtc[gtc$AccountNumber == each,]
  result<-rbind(result,gtcLoop)
}
```

Also, long time lurker, first time poster so let me know if I've done anything wrong in this question.

Comment: Is each entry of gtc$AccountNumber a single account number or is it a vector of whose length is sometimes greater than 1?

Comment: Each entry is a single number

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `==` by `%in%`:

```
gtc <- data.frame(AccountNumber = sample(c(match, "something"), 10, replace = TRUE))

gtc[gtc$AccountNumber %in% match,]
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Any idea why '==' works, but only for some of the results?

Answer (score 0):

Just to tag onto Qaswed's answer (+1), you need to understand what is happening when you compute vector comparisons like `==`.  See:

```
?`==`
```

and

```
?`%in%`
```

then try something like `1 == c(1,2)` and `1 %in% c(1,2)`.

The reason you are getting half the results is because the row subset is using the first evaluation only, as in:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1:5), acct_cd = letters[1:5])
df[df$acct_cd == c("a","c"),] # this is wrong, for demo only
df[df$acct_cd %in% c("a","c"),] # this is correct
```